# Avoiding ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when using onTouchEvent

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm running into this error:

```
09-13 18:20:50.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
09-13 18:20:50.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.view.MotionEvent.getY(MotionEvent.java:792)
09-13 18:20:50.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2040)
```

Which there is an issue for here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10238#c6

I get this error when I try to pass a MotionEvent form one ListView to another. However, this only occurs when one ListView has views with onClickListeners.

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !requestedFocus) {
        view.requestFocus();
        requestedFocus = true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        requestedFocus = false;
    }

    if(view == leftListView && view.isFocused()) {
        rightListView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    } else if(view == rightListView && view.isFocused()) {
        leftListView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return false;
}
```

With the code above everything works fine until the `rightListView` dynamically loads view's that have onClickListeners on them. Then any MotionEvent's that this view passes to the `leftListView` causes the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Events from the `leftListView` to the `rightListView` work as expected though.

This seems to happen because AbsListView's mActivePointerId == INVALID_POINTER, e.g. -1. I tried using reflection to change this value...but it didn't help.

So, my question is, is there any work around for this?

My goal is to sync the two ListView's scrolling, so I'm willing to scrap this method if another one is viable. I have tried using ScrollListeners but they cause other problems.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have an array and this array for example has a size of 9 and you are using index[10].